# Using Android to submit to a Google Spreadsheet Form

Tags: android, post, spreadsheet, google-forms

First time asking a question here. Usually I can find my answer without having to ask, but this time I'm stuck and can't figure out what I'm missing.

I'm just trying to have my Android app fill out a form on a website and submit it. I don't need the app to do anything with any data being sent back, just fill out the form and submit it. Basically I'm trying to collect the results of a voting app. I thought form submission would be simple so I created a Google Spreadsheet and made a form out of it. I figured I'd point the Android app to the form and then I would have all the data in the spreadsheet for later viewing. I can't get the Android app to actually fill out the form though. Here's the resources.

[Form](https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?hl=en_US&formkey=dDlwZzh4bGFvNFBxUmRsR0d2VTVhYnc6MQ&ifq)

[Spreadsheet](https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApTl61fIWzKqdDlwZzh4bGFvNFBxUmRsR0d2VTVhYnc&hl=en_US)

```
private void submitVote(String outcome) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?hl=en_US&amp;formkey=dDlwZzh4bGFvNFBxUmRsR0d2VTVhYnc6MQ&amp;ifq");

    List<BasicNameValuePair> results = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.0.single", cardOneURL));
    results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.1.single", outcome));
    results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.2.single", cardTwoURL));

    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(results));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("YOUR_TAG", "An error has occurred", e);
    }
    try {
        client.execute(post);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("YOUR_TAG", "An error has occurred", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("YOUR_TAG", "An error has occurred", e);
    }
}
```

I made both the form and the spreadsheet public so feel free to mess around with it and try and get it to work yourself.

I get no errors from my program, no compile errors, no errors in DDMS. When I actually run the program and click the button that executes this code I can see the delay since right now this is in the UI thread, so I know it's executing it. It appears as if everything is working perfectly, but my spreadsheet doesn't update at all.

Any thoughts? I'm sure it's something stupid that I'm missing, but any help would be appreciated.

Here's the updated code with lots of logging and debugging stuff.

```
private void submitVote(String outcome) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?hl=en_US&amp;formkey=dDlwZzh4bGFvNFBxUmRsR0d2VTVhYnc6MQ&amp;ifq");

    List<BasicNameValuePair> results = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.0.single", cardOneURL));
    results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.1.single", outcome));
    results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.2.single", cardTwoURL));

    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(results));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("YOUR_TAG", "An error has occurred", e);
    }
    try {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);
        Log.e("RESPONSE", "info: " + httpResponse);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.i("words", line);   
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReadingView.class);
        intent.putExtra("html", line);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("YOUR_TAG", "client protocol exception", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("YOUR_TAG", "io exception", e);
    }
}
```

I use ReadingView.class for something else in my app, but hijacked it for this logging purpose right now. It only has an onCreate() method, which is below.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.readingview);

    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //mWebView.loadUrl(getIntent().getExtras().getString("url"));
    mWebView.loadData(getIntent().getExtras().getString("html"), "text/html", "utf-8");
}
```

Also worth noting that in the DDMS it only logs one output of line. I believe this is just because the html code is returned all as one line. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is a great article that might be helpful to you.
http://www.morningcopy.com.au/tutorials/how-to-style-google-forms/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So I finally figured out what was going on. Through messing with manually encoding answers to the end of the form POST url I was able to find that the url it gave when viewing the source had encoding issues of it's own in it.

Here's the url from source:

```
<form action="https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?hl=en_US&amp;formkey=dDlwZzh4bGFvNFBxUmRsR0d2VTVhYnc6MQ&amp;ifq" method="POST" id="ss-form">
```

But here's what it needs to be to actually work in the above code:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?hl=en_US&formkey=dDlwZzh4bGFvNFBxUmRsR0d2VTVhYnc6MQ
```

The extra amp; was what was messing it up. For whatever reason it works without the last &ifq too, so I left that off. Anyway, here's completed code:

```
private void submitVote(String outcome) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?hl=en_US&formkey=dDlwZzh4bGFvNFBxUmRsR0d2VTVhYnc6MQ");

    List<BasicNameValuePair> results = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.0.single", cardOneURL));
    results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.1.single", outcome));
    results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.2.single", cardTwoURL));

    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(results));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("YOUR_TAG", "An error has occurred", e);
    }
    try {
        client.execute(post);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("YOUR_TAG", "client protocol exception", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("YOUR_TAG", "io exception", e);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else when trying to work with Google Spreadsheet Forms. And thanks to @pandre for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up this question. I'm trying to do a similar thing and am a noob dev so bear with me. What is the web view for in OnCreate? Do you make a native Android form with text field and button to submit and then call SubmitVote()? If so, then what is the point of the web view?

Comment: can you please tell me how to find the URL of the form ?

Comment: The Apache HTTP Client that the above example uses was [removed](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) in Android 6.0. How can the same thing be accomplished with [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)?

Answer (score 5):

The format, entry.0.single might not work in many cases. You must always find the proper id of the elements to create your POST request. This [article](http://codesmith.in/post-data-google-drive-sheet-through-mobile-app/) provides the proper way to post data to a Google docs sheet via android app.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the source for [Acra](http://code.google.com/p/acra/). This uploads stack traces to a Google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are not seing errors because you are printing exceptions in the wrong way.
You are using `e.printStackTrace();` which does not appear in DDMS/Logcat.

You should use instead
`Log.e("YOUR_TAG, "An error has occurred", e);`

which will log your error in DDMS/Logcat. You should see the stacktrace of the exception, and it will help you understand what's wrong.

EDIT:
Have you checked what is returned in `client.execute(post);` ?
You should check what is being returned in the POST response by doing:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);
```

You can also run the application in debug mode and check where it is crashing / stopping

Comment: I guess that would help huh? I put that in and still not getting anything in DDMS. I updated my original post too so others don't focus on that. I just get a message about "Window already focused", and that message is there even without the above code. Basically they submit their vote and then two new pictures come up to vote on. Could it be something with Google Forms?

Comment: I'll check that out when I get home. I'm not sure what response I should expect actually, since I don't need it for the application. Is there a default form response on submit that I can check for? Also, there are no crashes when running the program, it acts like everything if fine, but the results never show up in the spreadsheet. Just trying to be clear.

Comment: OK, with the response I get a webpage in text html format. However, when I try and log it in DDMS, it cuts off with ... at the end. I thought that this might just be DDMS not able to display it all, so I tried having the app load it in a webview but the webview just returns a blank white screen with the text "null" on it. I'm going to update my original post to show my logging methods. It's worth noting that the html source returned does not seem to match the start of the html source of the usual thank you page after clicking submit.

Comment: Doing more research, here's the page that's trying to come back from httpResponse. It's just a generic error page. I found it when trying to manually mess with url encoding in the address bar just for grins. If you look at the source for this page it's the same html string that DDMS cuts off from the response. Still no idea where to go from here with this.  https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?hl=en_US&amp;formkey=dDlwZzh4bGFvNFBxUmRsR0d2VTVhYnc6MQ&amp;ifq&entry.0.single=md

Comment: I'd mark your answer as useful but I don't have enough rep to do that apparently. Sorry. I gave you props in the answer I found though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So the cardOneUrl's are text edit fields in a layout.xml "results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.0.single", cardOneURL));" Thanks, Joe