# HTTP POST to Google Form from iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, google-forms

I am working on a POST request and have been using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358002/submit-data-to-google-spreadsheet-form-from-objective-c). There is a lot of documentation NSUrlRequest (and connection) but I am having trouble figuring out why the request won't work.

1. I have performed a successful POST using an HTTP Dev Client using this code

   ```
   entry.0.single=name&entry.1.single=location&entry.4.single=phoneNumber&entry.2.single=order????&pageNumber=0&backupCache=
   ```
2. The 4 variables (name, location, phoneNumber, order) are all linked to textFields in the app.

   ```
   - (IBAction)placeOrder:(id)sender {
       NSURL *nsURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"url"];
       NSMutableURLRequest *nsMutableURLRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:nsURL];

       // Set HTTP method to POST
       [nsMutableURLRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

       // Set up the parameters to send.
       NSString *paramDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@&%@=%@&%@=%@&%@=%@&pageNumber=0&backupCache=",@"entry.0.single", _name, @"entry.1.single", _location, @"entry.4.single", _phoneNumber, @"entry.2.single", _order];

       // Encode the parameters to default for NSMutableURLRequest.
       NSData *paramData = [paramDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

       // Set the NSMutableURLRequest body data.
       [nsMutableURLRequest setHTTPBody: paramData];


       // Create NSURLConnection and start the request.
       NSURLConnection *nsUrlConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:nsMutableURLRequest delegate:self];

       [ nsUrlConnection start];

   }
   ```

I think I might be missing something subtle but I have been pouring through stackoverflow and developer documentation. Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Make sure your controller implements the NSURLConnectionDelegate, and look at what's coming back (if anything) in connection:didReceiveResponse

Comment: Depending on whether or not you care about the data response you'd also want to implement `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`

Comment: I implemented the NSURLConnectionDelegate in the .h file like so:   interface HelloWorldViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate> However, I get an error stating that 'connection' is an undeclared identifier in the .m file for the 'connection:didReceiveResponse' code. Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to implement the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol, put `[nsUrlConnection setDelegate:self];` into your code and add the `-connectionDidFinishLoading:`, `-connection:didReceiveData:` and `-connectionDidFailWithError:` methods into your code and capture the response data:

```
.h
NSMutableData *responseData;

.m
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"CONNECTION ERROR: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly I need to do in the .h file. I am having trouble declaring 'NSMutableData *responseData;' Thanks

Comment: It's declare as a standard instance variable: @interface EDViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate> { NSMutableData *responseData; }

Comment: Perfect. This has been remarkably helpful and I appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

I did this task by using Swift. Check it out in this repo: https://github.com/goktugyil/QorumLogs

Here is the tutorial of how to set it up:
https://github.com/goktugyil/QorumLogs/blob/master/Log%20To%20GoogleDocs.md

Heres the code to do it:

```
private static func sendError(#text: String) {
    var url = NSURL(string: formURL)
    var postData = formField1 + "=" + text
    postData += "&" + formField2 + "=" + "anothertext"                
    postData += "&" + formField3 + "=" + "anothertext" 
    postData += "&" + formField4 + "=" + "anothertext" 

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPBody = postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: nil, startImmediately: true)
}
```

Comment: I'm no sure if thats possible

Comment: @Esqarrouth...its possible...but how to do not getting...here is the link for that...https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ios


but How to do not getting