# App crashes after failed response from web server

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I have the following code to log into a web server from my iOS app. The app logs in correctly although the "login failed" alert displays. Also, if the incorrect username/pass is entered and the app crashes.

I'm not sure if I have the error handling incorrect or the syntax is wrong.

the console output on a crash (incorrect username/pass entered) with response code 500:

```
    PostData: username=ghh&password=hhhh
2013-07-19 16:10:18.477 appName [11414:907] Response code: 500
```

and here's the output on login success (username/pass is correct) with Response code: 200:

```
    PostData: username=user-2&password=user-2
2013-07-19 16:15:28.757 appName [11430:907] Response code: 200
2013-07-19 16:15:28.758 appName [11430:907] Response ==> {"meta":[],"data":{"token":"JXVJdC05X0t9NnNqR1RBOzYkbFhUbk91KClRTH11fGk3MmVRcjZEaSVSO3hhemJ5WTQ2OFp5U2htZDtzc01tdHMkTCVGbi18JG4pMXlGITUpezZqSnJWR2dVMmQpWTh5c2h3RTVdVHgodUNdZFIpRTFjIWxKUXVJcnRnLXF0OUo="}}
2013-07-19 16:15:28.764 appName 11430:907] {
    data =     {
        token = "JXVJdC05X0t9NnNqR1RBOzYkbFhUbk91KClRTH11fGk3MmVRcjZEaSVSO3hhemJ5WTQ2OFp5U2htZDtzc01tdHMkTCVGbi18JG4pMXlGITUpezZqSnJWR2dVMmQpWTh5c2h3RTVdVHgodUNdZFIpRTFjIWxKUXVJcnRnLXF0OUo=";
    };
    meta =     (
    );
```

here's the login method:

```
- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {
    @try {

        if([[txtUsername text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
            [self alertStatus:@"Please enter both Username and Password" :@"Login Failed!"];
        } else {
            NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[txtUsername text],[txtPassword text]];
            NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://*******.net/api/token"];

            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

            NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
            if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
            {
                NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

                // extract token from json
                NSError *error = nil;
                NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:0 error:&error];
                NSString *token = [[responseDict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"token"];

                // save token string to nsuserdefaults
                NSString *valueToSave = token;
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                 setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"token"];

                SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
                NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
                NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
                NSLog(@"%d",success);
                if(success == 1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                    [self alertStatus:@"Logged in Successfully." :@"Login Success!"];

                } else {

                    NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"error_message"];
                    [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Login Failed!"];

                }

            } else {
                if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Login Failed!"];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Login Failed." :@"Login Failed!"];
    }
}
```

not sure if this helps, but here's the some error output. Line 5 is where it gets caught - "trap":

```
CoreFoundation`CFHash:
0x32119530:  push   {r4, r7, lr}
0x32119532:  mov    r4, r0
0x32119534:  add    r7, sp, #4
0x32119536:  cbnz   r4, 0x32119544            ; CFHash + 20
**0x32119538:  trap**   
0x3211953a:  blx    0x32217a7c                ; symbol stub for: -[NSOrderedSet intersectsSet:]
0x3211953e:  movs   r1, #9
0x32119540:  blx    0x32217b4c                ; symbol stub for: __61-[NSOrderedSet sortedArrayFromRange:options:usingComparator:]_block_invoke_0
0x32119544:  ldrd   r2, r3, [r4]
0x32119548:  cmp    r2, #0
0x3211954a:  ubfx   r0, r3, #8, #10
0x3211954e:  beq    0x32119572                ; CFHash + 66
0x32119550:  movw   r1, #61284
0x32119554:  movt   r1, #2114
0x32119558:  add    r1, pc
0x3211955a:  ldr    r1, [r1]
0x3211955c:  cmp    r2, r1
0x3211955e:  beq    0x32119572                ; CFHash + 66
0x32119560:  movw   r1, #57172
0x32119564:  movt   r1, #2114
0x32119568:  add    r1, pc
0x3211956a:  ldr.w  r1, [r1, r0, lsl #2]
0x3211956e:  cmp    r2, r1
0x32119570:  bne    0x32119588                ; CFHash + 88
0x32119572:  movw   r1, #53054
0x32119576:  movt   r1, #2114
0x3211957a:  add    r1, pc
0x3211957c:  ldr.w  r0, [r1, r0, lsl #2]
0x32119580:  ldr    r1, [r0, #24]
0x32119582:  mov    r0, r4
0x32119584:  cbnz   r1, 0x3211959e            ; CFHash + 110
0x32119586:  pop    {r4, r7, pc}
0x32119588:  movw   r0, #2272
0x3211958c:  movt   r0, #2113
0x32119590:  add    r0, pc
0x32119592:  ldr    r1, [r0]
0x32119594:  mov    r0, r4
0x32119596:  pop.w  {r4, r7, lr}
0x3211959a:  b.w    0x32215fbc                ; objc_msgSend$shim
0x3211959e:  pop.w  {r4, r7, lr}
0x321195a2:  bx     r1
```

thanks for any help with this :)

Comment: Can you please provide the exception from NSLog? I'd highly recommend using the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol and asynchronous requests, though

Comment: @Julian I've added some error code. as far as the NSLog output I get 0
2013-07-19 16:27:23.652 appName[11430:907] PostData: username=user-2&password=user-2j
2013-07-19 16:27:24.038 appName [11430:907] Response code: 500

Comment: I don't see a reason why the app should crash. But I'd really recommend using the Delegate protocol. See my answer in this post, it shows an low-level implementation... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748132/http-post-to-google-form-from-ios-app/17750061#17750061

Comment: I think it's crashing because of the error handling on the server.

Comment: when program execution stops at breakpoint, in the debugger can you execute bt command and post stacktrace ? (lldb)bt

Comment: Clearly the comparator block of the `NSOrderedSet` `-sortedArray...` method is nil. Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the "Connection Failed" alert is always displayed is, from the JSON response you posted, there is no object in the returned JSON dictionary for the key "success". Which means `objectForKey` returns nil and `integerValue` called on nil returns 0.

The reason for the crash is that, when the login fails there will be no token (I'm assuming that). Therefore, `token` will be nil and passing nil to `-[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]`
raises an invalid argument exception.

What you need to do is change the code as shown below.

```
            // extract token from json
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:0 error:&error];
            NSString *token = [[responseDict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"token"];

            if (token)     // make sure token is not nil
            {
                 // save token string to nsuserdefaults
                 NSString *valueToSave = token;
                 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"token"];
            }

            SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
            NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
            NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
            NSInteger success = token ? 1 : 0;   // token was sent = login successful
            NSLog(@"%d",success);
```

Comment: By the way `responseDict` and `jsonData` have the same content. You don't need to parse the received data again.

Comment: thank you! that worked for the login success. If, however, an incorrect password is entered the app crashes still with a Response code: 500. I would have thought that if success != 1 then it should just run the else statement and not crash like that.

Comment: thanks for your help again! I got it working. I just had to change the else statement on a login failure. :)