# it works only with English String (Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, string, forms, text

My question comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358002/submit-data-to-google-spreadsheet-form-from-objective-c), It works perfectly when I enter an English text, but empty cell appears in Responses when I use other language like Arabic and French.

The problem may be in Xcode, because when I enter arabic text from a site it appears on Responses.

I have tried putting `inputString` between English letters or symbols, but with no result.

Here's the code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1pyKGrF-h9aSC2lrKtuacxMctfVBZv_yNmjoxA4cZIc8/formResponse"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//data to send
NSString *postData = @"entry.496878440=";
postData=[postData stringByAppendingString:inputString];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

### EDIT:

It is printed fine on screen using `NSLog`. Also, when I compare strings using `isEqualToString`, even using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

Comment: Try to log your postData with NSLog after appending the string. What happens?

Comment: It is OK when I print it using NSLog.