# Sending data from iOS application to a Google spreadsheet

Tags: ios, swift, google-apps-script, google-api

I am making an app that will allow users to send data to a google spreadsheet. The app is an order form that has different fields for the items and names etc, then they user will be able to go back to the app and enter their order number and view weather or not the order is complete or not.

With other systems I have been able to simply use a URL that contained the data that was being sent the service, although Google spreadsheets does not seem to have that, I have been playing around with the script editor and thought I could use that to do something of that nature but could not figure it out.

So here is what I want to do, user submits data and that data is logged then the spreadsheet creates a new order number for that data line entry and returns it the device. What is the simplest way to send data to a Google spreadsheet? I have looked at their Drive API for iOS but I am using swift and they're guides are partially in swift and Objective-C; it's just a mess and I can't even get their example code to run.

Comment: google for the spreadsheets api

Comment: He said he did but it is half in objective C and is a mess.

Comment: @36-by-design It really is, they say they have a swift version but it links to the objective-c version and there is mismatching instructions and such. It is a mess.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358002/submit-data-to-google-spreadsheet-form-from-objective-c) might help.

Comment: Hello @MicrosoftDave did you get solution for your problem. I want to do the same using swift, please help me if you found any solution. Thnaks in advance.