# Source code for filling a google spreadshseet using android app

Tags: android, spreadsheet, google-docs-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Android to submit to a Google Spreadsheet Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174962/using-android-to-submit-to-a-google-spreadsheet-form)

I am new to Android developement and am developing an app for a book-renting website of our campus. I want to develope an activity in my Android project which allows the user to specify required details like name, adress etc. and also the name of the book he wants to rent. There is a google doc form available already for the web-version of the service. How do I populate that spreadsheet by taking in values from my app and forwading to that spreadsheet. I need a source code for it.

Comment: Are you looking for APIs to write data to Google docs documents? -- https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Comment: Seems to be a good source, but I really don't understand such hardcore coding. If someone could provide a link to an easier way of fulfillinf my task...

Answer (score 0):

This helped me: [Using Android to submit to a Google Spreadsheet Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174962/using-android-to-submit-to-a-google-spreadsheet-form). I have 2 working apps that send data to Google forms, so if you have follow up questions, I can help.

By the way, I originally found the above link just by searching Google for "send data to google form android". As you may know, there are a lot of useful existing questions and answers on a variety of topics, if you learn to look for them.