# Android Google Docs - Form

Tags: android, google-docs-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Android to submit to a Google Spreadsheet Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174962/using-android-to-submit-to-a-google-spreadsheet-form)

I want to create a Form in Android using which i would like to dump the data into a Google Form. I have been trying to find a good resource to understand how it can be done.

I see the ACRA Lib does this and have been looking for some kinda lib to be able to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer, but if so, this helped me: [Using Android to submit to a Google Spreadsheet Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174962/using-android-to-submit-to-a-google-spreadsheet-form). I have 2 working apps that send data to Google forms, so if you have follow up questions, I can help.

Note that Google just changed Google forms pretty significantly, but you can still use legacy forms with the solution linked to above, I think, though I haven't tried it yet. It seems that you have to create the spreadsheet first, then choose "Create a legacy form" from the Tools menu in that spreadsheet.

Comment: yes i am. i will look into it :D