# Android - how to obtain spreadsheet form key

Tags: android, forms, google-sheets

I wanted the app to fill details onto the spreadsheet using HTTP post. For that i referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174962/using-android-to-submit-to-a-google-spreadsheet-form) link.
It is working fine with the public spreadsheet created by the person who asked the question in the above link.. But now i wanted to create my own spreadsheet and test. But i am unable to fetch the form key for the spreadsheet i created. I also refered [this](http://blog.dfarooq.com/2012/10/using-google-spreadsheets-as-database.html) link but that did not help me. How can i get the form key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your spreadsheet online and go to `Form -> Edit Form`.  A dialog will popup, something like this:

[image: popup]

Simply copy everything after `formkey=`

Comment: this is pretty old way to obtain form key. Now itseems google has changed the way to do this. here is wat i get if do as u suggested http://i.imgur.com/kyP4XGK.png

Comment: @sureshcheemalamudi That method still works. I just tried it out. I haven't seen the UI you linked to though.

Comment: But am still getting the way i showed it to you, any idea why is this happening?