# Android App--How to Embed a Google Form into a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-forms

I know this is a long shot, but I really can't find any tutorials for what I want to do. I am in the middle of creating an Android app, and the next thing I want to do is embed a Google Form into a fragment [as my app uses swipeable views]. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174962/using-android-to-submit-to-a-google-spreadsheet-form), but this doesn't seem to be the entire code. Does anyone know what the entire code looks like, or have any other solutions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own UI for all the fields and then send a POST http request with the data to the google form URL. You'll have to find the exact ids of the input elements and create a key value pair for the same. [Here](http://codesmith.in/post-data-google-drive-sheet-through-mobile-app/) is an article which details the complete process with the required android code.