# Using HttpURLConnection on Android to submit to a Google Form

Tags: android, post, google-sheets, httpurlconnection, google-forms

I used the method in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174962/using-android-to-submit-to-a-google-spreadsheet-form) question to post to a Google Spreadsheet form from my Android app. The method in the question uses the Apache HTTP Client which was [removed](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) in Android 6.0. While it is possible to use the Apache HTTP Client on Android 6.0, I'd like to implement the same functionally with [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). How can I post to a Google Spreadsheet form using HttpURLConnection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the method you post a Google Spreadsheet is similar to the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174962/using-android-to-submit-to-a-google-spreadsheet-form).

I recommend you to use a 3rd party library which called [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

**okhttp** is reliable, easy to use, and it also has several additional features.

The following is the sample code. Hope it would be helpful.

```
    // perpare httpclient
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setConnectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.setReadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // prepare post params
    RequestBody body = new FormEncodingBuilder()
            .add("entry.0.single", cardOneURL)
            .add("entry.1.single", outcome)
            .add("entry.2.single", cardTwoURL)
            .build();

    // prepare request
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/your_spreadsheet")
            .post(body)
            .build();

    try {

        client.newCall(request).execute();  // send your request

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        // do something
    }
```